# Displaying Decrypted Data on a Webpage, without the Webpage Being able to read or save it

Tags: cryptography, public-key-encryption, metamask, nacl-cryptography

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

The user has a public-private keypair. The public key is known, while the private key is kept secret by the user.

The webserver has data that was encrypted using the user's public key.

I want the user to be able to decrypt the webserver data using their private key (using a browser extension like MetaMask that has their private key stored), and then display that data to the user in a web page, while also PREVENTING the web page from being able to store that data.

Any suggestions on how this might be done?

Comment: If the user can see it then the user can save it.

Comment: I'm not trying to stop the user from saving it; I'm trying to stop the website itself from being able to save it. Like suppose it's important personal information--I wouldn't want a malicious website displaying the data to save that information in plaintext. I would want the website to be forced to display it once and then never show it again.

Comment: I don't know if this is a thing, but maybe a protected iframe? Or maybe a <secret>(encrypted data)</secret> tag; the wallet, because it's a browser extension, could grab the encrypted data inside the <secret> and then replace it with the decrypted data after the page has rendered. Hopefully the webpage won't be able to run a script to grab data from its own DOM and read that <secret> data after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

Update; you can indeed do this with an iframe. Iframes are surprisingly secure actually. The browser effectively partitions the iframe from its parent, and vice-versa, even though to the user they look like they're the same page to the user. You can inject private information into a protected iframe on a webpage without giving that webpage access to the data. This is the method Stripe uses to embed credit-card entry fields directly into websites.